# What was the quantity of the most expensive item ordered using Pandas

Tags: pandas

My DF is which is `ascending=False` is below

`chipo_name_price_desc`

```
        item_name   item_price
2624    Steak Salad Bowl    9.39
4419    Steak Salad Bowl    9.39
4036    Steak Salad Bowl    9.39
1825    Barbacoa Salad Bowl 9.31
3115    Carnitas Salad Bowl 9.19
5000    Meat Salad Bowl     9.39
```

What was the quantity of the most expensive item ordered?
`chipo_name_price_desc.loc[chipo_name_price_desc['item_name'] == 'Steak Salad Bowl'].count()`

Expected out:
Steak Salad Bowl  3
Meat Salad Bowl   1

is there any better way than this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Using `Series.max` and `Series.shape`

Without using `sort` we can get the `max` of `item_price` and then get the quantity with `Series.shape`:

```
df[df['item_price'] == df['item_price'].max()].shape[0]

#Out
3
```

---

#### Using `GroupBy` after `sort`

Or if you used sort, we can get the first group with `GroupBy` and check the size:

```
grps = [grp for _, grp in df.groupby('item_name', sort=False)]
print(grps[0].shape[0])

#Out
3
```

Not very general, but if you want to get a certain group after groupby, use `GroupBy.get_group` by index name:

```
df.groupby('item_name').get_group('Steak Salad Bowl').shape[0]

#Out
3
```

Comment: just one more query if 2 item_name are there of same item_price, then what need to be do. In the output it has item_name, item_price has to appear of 2 items

Comment: Can you edit your example data to showcase this problem? @ain

Comment: added sample data and expected out

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.max.html):

```
df['item price'].eq(df['item price'].max()).sum()
#3
```

or

```
df['item price'].eq(df['item price'].max()).count()
#3
```